# Weblogic package deployment plan inside ear

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, solace, resource-adapter

I'm trying to install the solace weblogic resource adapter as described here https://dev.solace.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Solace-JMS-Integration-with-WebLogic.pdf

The problem is that we are not allowed to manually deploy anything inside weblogic with our infrastructure. This means that in order to get the rar inside weblogic I have to package it inside the ear that also contains the war for our application.

The problem is that once the resource adapter is deployed on the server it still needs to be configured which requires manual intervention and that is again not allowed.

When manually configuring the resource adapter locally it creates a deployment plan that it then uses to configure the resource adapter when the server starts.

My question is, is there a way to somehow pre-package the deployment plan for the rar inside the ear so that I can configure it at build time?

Answer (score 2):

Weblogic handles the deployment plans separately from applications. It is not possible to deploy a deployment plan by pre-packaging it inside of the RAR file.

If you are not permitted to use the Weblogic console, another option would be to
use the weblogic.Deployer Java command which handles the application and the plan separately, but it still gets the deployment done in one command without using the console.